# reflection on embedded structs

Tags: go

Given a struct like so:

```
type B struct {
    X string
    Y string
}

type D struct {
    B
    Z string
}
```

I want to reflect on D and get to the fields X, Y, Z.

Intuitively, before attempting the solution, I was assuming I would be able to traverse the struct D and get all fields using reflection (X, Y, Z) and won't have to deal with B.

But as you can see, I only see the embedded struct B using reflection and not its fields.

http://play.golang.org/p/qZQD5GdTA8

Is there a way I can make B fully transparent when reflecting on D?

Why do I want this?

Imaging a common struct (B in the example here), that is used in multiple other structs by using embedding. Using reflection, the attempt is to copy D into another similar struct in a different package. The destination struct for copying will have all attributes flatly laid out (no embedding there). So there is a mismatch from the source to the destination (embedding vs no embedding) but all the attributes flatly laid out are the same. I don't want to create custom solutions for each struct.

Answer (score 42):

The 'transparency' you expected is just syntactic sugar and has nothing to do with the data representation. If you want to have a function that flattens your data structure, you would have to write it by yourself.

For example ([On play](http://play.golang.org/p/EzG8vDmyko)):

```
func DeepFields(iface interface{}) []reflect.Value {
    fields := make([]reflect.Value, 0)
    ifv := reflect.ValueOf(iface)
    ift := reflect.TypeOf(iface)

    for i := 0; i < ift.NumField(); i++ {
        v := ifv.Field(i)

        switch v.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            fields = append(fields, DeepFields(v.Interface())...)
        default:
            fields = append(fields, v)
        }
    }

    return fields
}
```

Comment: perhaps you should check if the field is embedded before to flatten it if it is to simulate the 'transparency' the OP is expecting ? i.e. ``if v.Kind() == reflect.Struct && v.Anonymous{``

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code to collect all promoted field names as keys in map `m`:

```
func collectFieldNames(t reflect.Type, m map[string]struct{}) {

    // Return if not struct or pointer to struct.
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        t = t.Elem()
    }
    if t.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return
    }

    // Iterate through fields collecting names in map.
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        sf := t.Field(i)
        m[sf.Name] = struct{}{}

        // Recurse into anonymous fields.
        if sf.Anonymous {
            collectFieldNames(sf.Type, m)
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
m := make(map[string]struct{})
collectFieldNames(reflect.TypeOf((*D)(nil)), m)
for name := range m {
    fmt.Println(name)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KM6Znu1t-EY).

This program prints X, Y an Z as requested in the question, but also B because B is also a field name.

This function in this answer can be improved:

- Don't blow up on recursive type definitions.
- Do not include names repeated at the same level in the hierarchy.

The `typeField` function in [encoding/json/encode.go](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go) handles both of these issues.