# Recursively walk through nested structs

Tags: recursion, go, reflection

I want to build a method that takes a struct as an `interface{}` and returns `true` if any of the supplied struct's fields are nil.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
// ContainsNil returns true if any fields within the supplied structure are nil.
//
// If the supplied object is not a struct, the method will panic.
// Nested structs are inspected recursively.
// Maps and slices are not inspected deeply. This may change.
func ContainsNil(obj interface{}) bool {
    if obj == nil {
        return true
    }
    s := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(obj))
    for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
        f := s.Type().Field(i)
        field := s.Field(i)
        if fieldIsExported(f) { // Exported-check must be evaluated first to avoid panic.
            if field.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                if ContainsNil(field.Addr()) {
                    return true
                }
            } else {
                if field.IsNil() {
                    return true
                }
                if field.Interface() == nil {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

func fieldIsExported(field reflect.StructField) bool {
    log.Println(field.Name)
    return field.Name[0] >= 65 == true && field.Name[0] <= 90 == true
}
```

And a failing test:

```
func Test_ContainsNil_NilNestedValue_ReturnsTrue(t *testing.T) {
    someNestedStruct := &c.SomeNestedStruct{
        SomeStruct: c.SomeStruct{
            SomeString: nil,
        },
    }
    result := util.ContainsNil(someNestedStruct)
    assert.True(t, result)
}
```

The test code executes without panicking, but fails because the method returns `false` rather than `true`.

The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to properly pass the nested struct back into the recursive call to `ContainsNil`.

When recursive call is made for the nested structure, the `fieldIsExported` method returns `false` because it's not receiving the value that I would expect it to be receiving.

I expect `fieldIsExported` to receive "SomeStruct" on its first call, and receive "SomeString" on the second (recursive) call. The first call goes as expected, but on the second call, `fieldIsExported` receives "typ", when I would expect it to receive "SomeString".

I've done a bunch of research about using reflect on structs, but I haven't been able to get my head around this yet. Ideas?

References:

- [Pass by reference nested structures through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047424/pass-by-reference-nested-structures-through-reflection)
- [golang - reflection on embedded structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333494/golang-reflection-on-embedded-structs)
- https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/
- Lot's of googling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check if the current field is a struct **value**, but you never account for the case when it is a `reflect.Ptr` to a struct or something else, so your function never recurses for that case. Here is your function with the missing piece.

https://play.golang.org/p/FdLxeee9UU

```
// ContainsNil returns true if any fields within the supplied structure are nil.
//
// If the supplied object is not a struct, the method will panic.
// Nested structs are inspected recursively.
// Maps and slices are not inspected deeply. This may change.
func ContainsNil(obj interface{}) bool {
    if obj == nil {
        return true
    }
    s := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(obj))
    for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
        f := s.Type().Field(i)
        field := s.Field(i)
        if fieldIsExported(f) { // Exported-check must be evaluated first to avoid panic.
            if field.Kind() == reflect.Ptr { // case when it's a pointer or struct pointer
                if field.IsNil() {
                    return true
                }
                if ContainsNil(field.Interface()) {
                    return true
                }
            }
            if field.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                if ContainsNil(field.Addr()) {
                    return true
                }
            } else {
                if field.IsNil() {
                    return true
                }
                if field.Interface() == nil {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thanks so much for the assistance!